Failing to create azurerm_private_endpoint getting error unexpected status 400 (400 Bad Request) with error: SubscriptionNotRegisteredForFeature:
I am trying to create a private endpoint using terraform and am getting the error.  What could I be missing? What I find interesting is the same subscription has got private endpoint resources .
Error: creating Private Endpoint (Subscription: "***"
performing CreateOrUpdate: unexpected status 400 (400 Bad Request) with error: SubscriptionNotRegisteredForFeature: Subscription /subscriptions//resourceGroups//providers/Microsoft.Network/subscriptions/ is not registered for feature Microsoft.Network/AllowPrivateEndpoints required to carry out the requested operation.
│
│   with module.azurerm_private_endpoint.azurerm_private_endpoint.main,
│   on ../../factory/private-endpoint/main.tf line 1, in resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "main":
│    1: resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "main" {
main.tf
locals {
  team_name  = "devops"
  stack_name = "devops"

  location_abbreviations = { # map of location abbreviations according to naming conventions
    "southafricanorth" = "san"
    "westeurope"       = "euw"

  }
  resource_group_name = "${local.location_abbreviations[var.location]}-${var.environment}-${local.team_name}-rg-001"


  tags = { # list of tags
    env        = var.environment
    managed_by = "terraform"
    team       = local.team_name
  }
}


data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {}

data "terraform_remote_state" "platform" {
  backend = "azurerm"

  config = {
    subscription_id      = "********"
    resource_group_name  = "******"
    storage_account_name = "******"
    container_name       = "platform"
    key                  = "${var.environment}.tfstate"
  }
}


module "azurerm_resource_group" {
  source                  = "../../factory/resource-group"
  resource_group_name     = local.resource_group_name
  resource_group_location = var.location

}

module "azurerm_application_insights" {

  source                       = "../../factory/application-insights"
  app_insights_name            = "${local.location_abbreviations[var.location]}-${var.environment}-${local.team_name}-ai-001"
  location                     = var.location
  resource_group_name          = local.resource_group_name
  application_type             = "web"
  log_analytics_workspace_name = "${local.location_abbreviations[var.location]}-${var.environment}-${local.team_name}-logwkspace-001"
  tags                         = local.tags
  # Disable IP masking (captures the actual client IP address)
  disable_ip_masking = true
}

module "azurerm_private_endpoint" {
  source                                                    = "../../factory/private-endpoint"
  name                                                      = "${local.location_abbreviations[var.location]}-${var.environment}-lulapay-appInsight-endpoint-001"
  location                                                  = var.location
  resource_group_name                                       = local.resource_group_name
  subnet_id                                                 = data.terraform_remote_state.platform.outputs.private_endpoints_subnet_id
  private_service_connection_name                           = "app-insights-privatelink-dns-zones"
  private_service_connection_is_manual_connection           = false
  private_service_connection_private_connection_resource_id = module.azurerm_application_insights.id
  tags                                                      = local.tags
  private_dns_zone_group_name                               = "application-insights-private-dns-zones"
  private_dns_zone_group_name_private_dns_zone_ids          = [data.terraform_remote_state.platform.outputs.app_insights_privatelink_dns_zone_id]


}

# DNS A Record for Application Insights
resource "azurerm_private_dns_a_record" "example" {
  name                = "lulapay-app-insight-privatelink"
  zone_name           = split("/", trim(data.terraform_remote_state.platform.outputs.app_insights_privatelink_dns_zone_id, "/"))[7]
  resource_group_name = local.resource_group_name
  records             = [module.azurerm_private_endpoint.private_ip]
  ttl                 = 10
}
   

Module
resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "main" {


  # define endpoint name based on app service name
  name                = var.name
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  location            = var.location
  subnet_id           = var.subnet_id
  tags                = var.tags
  
   private_dns_zone_group {
    name = var.private_dns_zone_group_name
    private_dns_zone_ids = var.private_dns_zone_group_name_private_dns_zone_ids
  }
  private_service_connection {
    name                           = var.private_service_connection_name
    private_connection_resource_id = var.private_service_connection_private_connection_resource_id
    is_manual_connection           = var.private_service_connection_is_manual_connection
    

  }
}

When a check the feature is still on pending
$ az feature show --namespace Microsoft.Network --name AllowPrivateEndpoints
{
  "id": "/subscriptions/*********/providers/Microsoft.Features/providers/Microsoft.Network/features/AllowPrivateEndpoints",
  "name": "Microsoft.Network/AllowPrivateEndpoints",
  "properties": {
    "state": ***"Pending"***
  },
  "type": "Microsoft.Features/providers/features"
}


did you try using Force Feature Registration @NicholasNamacha as it taking lot of time to register try using az feature register --namespace Microsoft.Network --name AllowPrivateEndpoints

I did run that, I guess hence the pending status. I will give it sometime and check again later

You can try using the option skip_provider_registration = true? When set to true Terraform will skip checking for provider registration and run without it.

For it to work I had to include Azure Monitor Private Link Scope. Then link the private endpoint to that and it worked.
module "azurerm_application_insights" {

  source                       = "../../factory/application-insights"
  app_insights_name            = "${local.location_abbreviations[var.location]}-${var.environment}-${local.team_name}-ai-001"
  location                     = var.location
  resource_group_name          = local.resource_group_name
  application_type             = "web"
  log_analytics_workspace_name = "${local.location_abbreviations[var.location]}-${var.environment}-${local.team_name}-logwkspace-001"
  tags                         = local.tags
  # Disable IP masking (captures the actual client IP address)
  disable_ip_masking = true
}

resource "azurerm_monitor_private_link_scope" "lulapay-ampls" {
  name                = "${local.location_abbreviations[var.location]}-${var.environment}-${local.team_name}-ampls-endpoint-001"
  resource_group_name = local.resource_group_name
}

resource "azurerm_monitor_private_link_scoped_service" "lulapay-ampls-scoped" {
  name                = "${local.location_abbreviations[var.location]}-${var.environment}-${local.team_name}-amplsservice-001"
  resource_group_name = local.resource_group_name
  scope_name          = azurerm_monitor_private_link_scope.lulapay-ampls.name
  linked_resource_id  = module.azurerm_application_insights.id
}


module "azurerm_private_endpoint" {
  source                                                    = "../../factory/private-endpoint"
  name                                                      = "${local.location_abbreviations[var.location]}-${var.environment}-lulapay-appInsight-endpoint-001"
  location                                                  = var.location
  resource_group_name                                       = local.resource_group_name
  subnet_id                                                 = data.terraform_remote_state.platform.outputs.private_endpoints_subnet_id
  private_service_connection_name                           = "app-insights-privatelink-dns-zones"
  private_service_connection_is_manual_connection           = false
  private_service_connection_private_connection_resource_id = azurerm_monitor_private_link_scope.lulapay-ampls.id
  private_service_connection_subresource_names              = ["azuremonitor"]
  tags                                                      = local.tags
  private_dns_zone_group_name                               = "application-insights-private-dns-zones"
  private_dns_zone_group_name_private_dns_zone_ids          = [data.terraform_remote_state.platform.outputs.app_insights_privatelink_dns_zone_id]

}


resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone" "example" {
  name                = "privatelink.applicationinsights.azure.com"
  resource_group_name = "san-dev-lulapay-rg-001"
}

# DNS A Record for Application Insights
resource "azurerm_private_dns_a_record" "example" {
  name                = "lulapay-app-insight-privatelink"
  zone_name           = split("/", trim(azurerm_private_dns_zone.example.id, "/"))[7]
  resource_group_name = local.resource_group_name
  records             = [module.azurerm_private_endpoint.private_ip]
  ttl                 = 10
}



Registering the Microsoft.Network provider in subscription using  terraform.

The blocker mentioned unexpected status 400 (400 Bad Request) with error: SubscriptionNotRegisteredForFeature popups when the provider registrations of particular service is not reregistered under that subscription.
Since the command mentioned
$ az feature show --namespace Microsoft.Network --name AllowPrivateEndpoints

Results in the pending in registration it doesn't works as expected.
When I use skip_provider_registration  =  true  it still shows the error as mentioning that the registration was missing

As per the latest documentation of terraform we can register the required providers which misses permission. This will re-register the provider without missing any relevant permissions.
I tried to create a demo private end point with the  Microsoft.Network  with feature related to private endpoint gets enabled with this configuration will ensure the registration part of the provider and create private endpoint without any issue.
Configuration:

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
 skip_provider_registration = true
}

resource "azurerm_resource_provider_registration" "example" {
  name = "Microsoft.Network"

   feature {
    name       = "AllowPrivateEndpoints"
    registered = true
  }
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "vinays-rg"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
  name                = "vinay-network"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  depends_on = [ azurerm_resource_provider_registration.example ]
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "service" {
  name                 = "service"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.1.0/24"]
  private_link_service_network_policies_enabled = false
  
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "endpoint" {
  name                 = "vinay-endpoint"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.2.0/24"]

}

resource "azurerm_public_ip" "example" {
  name                = "vinay-pip"
  sku                 = "Standard"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  allocation_method   = "Static"

  depends_on = [ azurerm_resource_provider_registration.example ]
}

resource "azurerm_lb" "example" {
  name                = "vinay-lb"
  sku                 = "Standard"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  frontend_ip_configuration {
    name                 = azurerm_public_ip.example.name
    public_ip_address_id = azurerm_public_ip.example.id
  }
}

resource "azurerm_private_link_service" "example" {
  name                = "cvvprivatelink"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  nat_ip_configuration {
    name      = azurerm_public_ip.example.name
    primary   = true
    subnet_id = azurerm_subnet.service.id
  }

  load_balancer_frontend_ip_configuration_ids = [
    azurerm_lb.example.frontend_ip_configuration[0].id,
  ]
}

resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "example" {
  name                = "provk-endpoint"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  subnet_id           = azurerm_subnet.endpoint.id

  private_service_connection {
    name                           = "vinay-privateserviceconnection"
    private_connection_resource_id = azurerm_private_link_service.example.id
    is_manual_connection           = false
  }
}


Note:
If the requirement to enable feature to use this which I shared. If you want to re-register the Microsoft.Network remove features block from that resource.
Deployment:



Refer:
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/resource_provider_registration
azurerm_private_endpoint | Resources | hashicorp/azurerm | Terraform | Terraform Registry

Am getting  Error: applying features for Subscription Provider (Subscription: "a80c9dae-92b6-4da6-8e27-3c2c414767df" │ Provider Name: "Microsoft.Network"): Feature (Subscription: "******"  │ Provider Name: "Microsoft.Network" │ Feature Name: "AllowPrivateEndpoints") which requires manual approval should not be managed by terraform │ │   with azurerm_resource_provider_registration.example, │   on main.tf line 36, in resource "azurerm_resource_provider_registration" "example": │   36: resource "azurerm_resource_provider_registration" "example" { │

if I run az feature show --namespace Microsoft.Network --name PrivateEndpoints the status is not changing from pending @Vinay B

open portal and deregister Microsoft.Network once under subscription and once its done try again same code and sure you use depends_on for network related modules as i mentioned in the configuration  @NicholasNamacha

check with note point mentioned for clear understanding of the configuration changes hope this solution helps you @NicholasNamacha
